# Meteor: subscribe to external datasource

Tags: meteor

In Meteor I want to subscribe to events outside meteor and insert any updates in a collection, i.e.

```
external_subscriber.subscribe("some data");

external_subscriber.on('message', function(data) {
    meteor_collection.insert({newdata:data.toString()});
}));
```

Meteor tells me to run this in a fibre. Normally I would use async and futures, but this is not an async call. How to subscribe to external data and insert results in collections?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose call to meteor collection into new fiber as shown as follows-

```
external_subscriber.on('message', function(data) {
   new Fiber(()->
      meteor_collection.insert({newdata:data.toString()});
    ).run()
}));
```

This should work